# Bootstrap Carousel not moving as part of a Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the Bootstrap carousel in my Rails app. JQuery, Bootstrap and JS is all loaded and a working database set up. So I am wondering if there is a mistake in my code for the carousel. The first image is displayed but it is not changing and clicking the arrows does not make it move to the next.

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
     <div class="item<%= " active" if product == @products.first %>">
       <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
         <%= product.name %>
       </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried enclosing your bootstrap carousel initializer within 
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
...
}
after loading your bootstrap files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS is not loaded that why it is not working

make sure that you include bootstrap js in your application.js or just include it in the layout

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is standing out as being an error necessarily but the approach that I've used previously that works takes a slightly different approach like this:

```
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <div class="item <%= 'active' if index == 0 %>">
      <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <%= product.name %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Also, have you double checked that you have the Bootstrap JS file loaded?

Edit: Based on the fact that the JS is still non-functioning I would expect that it's potentially an issue with the asset pipeline properly loading the JS assets. While you can include bootstrap through the CDN I would recommend that you add: `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` to your gem file and `bundle install`. This will add bootstrap via the Gem (and it's more of a Rails approach) and then you'll head into your `application.js` file and update the load order to look like this (assuming you have jquery_ujs):

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Just posted where I loaded Bootstrap, just to be sure. 
Your code works even less with me, now there is not even the image of the first product displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just to be sure this is where I load bootstrap, so far it didnt cause any issues but I only used it for a navbar so far.

```html
<head>
    <title>Rails1</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script scr="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  
  </head>
```